# c# modifying resource file in a pre-built application

Tags: c#, forms, resources

I have a win forms application written in C# which has a resource file, after this application has been built I want to alter the contents of the resource file, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Even if the resource file can be modified how will the app use it without changing the source code?

Comment: The application will be used as part of a self decrypting archive as such I need to encrypt a file (with a separate application) and then change the file that the (self decrypting archive) application already references so that it attempts to decrypt (using the passphrase the user provides) the correct file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised that I was doing this the wrong way around, instead of building an application and then attempting to modify the resources of that application on the fly I am not creating and building an application (including resources) on the fly and this seems to work perfectly for my purposes.